# Problema com inner join no MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Estou tentando criar uma *query* para trazer resultados que estão em diferentes tabelas no *MySQL*,3 mas não estou conseguindo.

Possuo experiencia em *JOIN* no *SQL*, mas estou apanhando um pouco para fazer no *MySQL*, podem me ajudar? Já consultei aqui no site, mas não consegui solucionar o meu problema. Pensei em *JOIN* e *subselects* para resolver meu problema.

Gostaria de relacionar e trazer como resultado as seguintes informações:

```
select nome from usuario 
select nome from entregadores
select nome from status
```

Pensei nesse *JOIN* aqui, mas está com erro.

```
select d.nome, c.nome, a.km, a.valor, a.valor_extra, a.data, b.nome from 
viagens A
inner join b.entregadores 
on (a.usuarios_id=d.usuarios_id)
inner join c.status
on (a.entregadores_id=b.entregadores_id)
inner join d.viagens
on (a.status_id=c.status_id)
```

Segue a estrutura das minhas tabelas:

**Tabela viagens:**

```
viagens_id
usuarios_id
entregadores_id
forma_pagamento_id
status_id
tipo_valor_id
endereco_origem
numero_origem
contato_origem
complemento_origem
ida_volta
data_horario
valor
valor_extra
observacoes
data_criado
data_modificado
user_modificou
distancia
ativo
deleted
```

**Tabela usuarios:**

```
usuarios_id
grupo_id
empresas_id
nome
login
senha
email
telefone
codigo_seguranca
departamento
thumb
ramal
data_criado
data_modificado
ativo
deleted
```

**Tabela status:**

```
status_id
nome
ativo
deleted
padrao
```

**Tabela entregadores:**

```
entregadores_id
veiculos_id
nome
cnh
telefone1
telefone2
placa
email
vencimento_cnh
foto_cnh
foto_doc
data_criado
data_modificado
ativo
deleted
```

Segue minha ultima execução da Query com as colunas com nome certo, apresentou outro erro no PhpMyadmin "Tinha colocado algumas colunas com nome errado, arrumei e rodei dessa forma a query select status.nome as statusNome, viagens.valor 
as viagemValor, viagens.distancia, viagens.valor_extra, 
entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens
natural join entregadores
natural join status
natural join usuarios
O PhpMyadmin trouxe o erro "#1267 - Combinação ilegal de collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) e (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) para operação '='""

select status.nome as statusNome, viagens.valor 
as viagemValor, viagens.distancia, viagens.valor_extra, 
entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens
natural join entregadores
natural join status
natural join usuarios

Comment: Tem como postar os atributos de cada tabela?

Comment: Editei o post com a estrutura das minhas tabelas, com o nome das colunas de cada uma.

Answer (score 1):

O join está com os alias trocados. O ON deve concordar com a tabela incluida ao join. Tendo que apenas a declaracao dos alias está errada e os joins não sequenciados, ficaria assim:

```
select d.nome, c.nome, a.km, a.valor, a.valor_extra, a.data, b.nome 
from 
viagens A
inner join entregadores B on (a.entregadores_id=b.entregadores_id) 
inner join status C on (a.status_id=c.status_id)
inner join viagens D on (a.usuarios_id=d.usuarios_id)
```

Comment: Tentei rodar dessa forma no PHPMyAdmin e não rodou. Editei o post com a estrutura das minhas tabelas e cada coluna delas.

Comment: Quando puder, coloca o erro que está sendo apresentado.

Comment: Tinha colocado algumas colunas com nome errado, arrumei e rodei dessa forma a query select status.nome as statusNome, viagens.valor 
as viagemValor, viagens.distancia, viagens.valor_extra, 
entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens
natural join entregadores
natural join status
natural join usuarios  
O PhpMyadmin trouxe o erro "#1267 - Combinação ilegal de collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) e (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) para operação '='"

Comment: O problema é que o collation utilizado nas tabelas está diferente, consequentemente o mysql não consegue fazer as comparacões.
No phpadmin tem que selecionar cada uma das tabelas envolvidas e verificar a estrutura, na coluna colacão ou collation para todas as colonas que possuirem valor eles deverão ser os mesmos, no seu caso acredito que todos deverão ser latin1_general_cl, isso para todas as tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que você está aplicando a junção está errada.
`viagens A inner join b.entregadores`, não faz sentido isso. Você tem que colocar o nome das duas tabelas envolvidos no JOIN.
O certo seria `viagens A inner join entregadores ON <condição>`.
Como as chaves estrangeiras que ligam as tabelas tem o mesmo nome, você pode usar o [natural join](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-natural-join.php).

Essa query aqui deve resolver o seu problema:

```
select status.nome as statusNome, viagens.nome as viagemNome, viagens.valor 
as viagemValor, viagens.km, viagens.valor_extra, viagens.data, 
entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens
natural join entregadores
natural join status
natural join usuarios
```

Comment: Tinha colocado algumas colunas com nome errado, arrumei e rodei dessa forma a query select status.nome as statusNome, viagens.valor 
as viagemValor, viagens.distancia, viagens.valor_extra, 
entregadores.nome as entregadorNome
from viagens
natural join entregadores
natural join status
natural join usuarios  
O PhpMyadmin trouxe o erro "#1267 - Combinação ilegal de collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) e (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) para operação '='"